# Возможно ли в Chrome - расширении обойти Content Security Policy для файлов с сервера nginx или локальных файлов?

Tags: javascript, html, json, chrome-extension, cors

1) Есть локальный сервер nginx (расположенный по адресу http://127.0.0.1/), у которого в разделе "html" располагается раздел appFolder, в котором лежит файл common.js.
Возможно ли chrome - расширению получать файл с данного сервера?

В моем случае при загрузке файла возникает ошибка:
Refused to load the script 'http://127.0.0.1/appFolder/common.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Соответственно, то, что я прописал в файле расширения manifest.json:
`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://127.0.0.1/appFolder/; object-src 'self'"`

2) Возможно ли также обойти Content Security Policy, если расширению нужно получить файлы с локального раздела (например, с file://C:/Users/mmwork/jsProjects/appFolder/common.js)?

Соответственно, мой параметр CSP в файле manifest.json:
`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' file://C:/Users/mmwork/jsProjects/appFolder/; object-src 'self'"`

Ошибка аналогична ошибке из первого пункта.

Comment: `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' file:///C:/Users/mmwork/jsProjects/appFolder/; object-src 'self'"` - после `file:` три слэша нужно.

Comment: Возможно, также потребуются соответствующие разрешения (permissions). Но там ошибка уже другая будет, если они нужны :)

Comment: @yar85 тут скорее всего и нужно указать в permissions. В последних версиях хрома ошибка CSP выдается в том числе, если нет домена в permissions.